# How to make multiple fbo work in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on 3d with kivy.I wanted to make bloom effect by postprocessing shader.I dont know how to pass multiple fbo in kivy..i can make one pass but cant make multiple pass..so,can any one help me?

Here is my code:

```
class SergioGameEngine(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

    self.canvas = RenderContext(size = self.size,clear_color=(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0))


    with self.canvas:

        self.viewport = Rectangle(size=(self.size), pos=self.pos)
        self.fbo = Fbo(size=self.size,
                            with_depthbuffer=True,
                            compute_normal_mat=True,
                            clear_color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.))
    self.fbo.shader.source = resource_find('simple.glsl')
    Loading meshes.....

    with self.fbo:
        self.cb = Callback(self.setup_gl_context)
        PushMatrix()



        self.setup_scene()
        PopMatrix()
        self.cb = Callback(self.reset_gl_context)


   self.canvas.shader.fs = fsi #this is postprocessing shader
   self.pm = Window.render_context['projection_mat']
   self.mm = Window.render_context['modelview_mat']
   self.canvas['projection_mat'] = self.pm
   self.canvas['modelview_mat'] = self.mm

def on_pos(self, instance, value):
    self.viewport.pos = (0.0,0.0)
    print(value)

def on_texture(self, instance, value):
    self.viewport.texture = self.fbo.texture


fsi = """postprocessing shader"""
```

Now,canvas viewport is updated with fbo texture...
and the viewport texture is used as sampler on canvas fragment shader and i can edit that screen texture ...but the thing is how can i take canvas outputed frametexture and pass again as sampler for reusing as screen shader?

:)

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry,im new to stackoverflow

Comment: Post an example of what you're doing, and where you hit a barrier.

Comment: i updated question

Comment: I sorted it out by updating texture of 2nd fbo :) ..

Comment: Would you mind to share your solution?